# jQuery: Show code within element nested

Tags: html, nested

When the user clicks a button, I want to show all the HTML thats within a div container. I know how to do that but I need the code to come out properly nested/with proper indentation.

Is there a way for me to achieve this? maybe with a jQuery plugin?

I will display the code within another container inside a div. I can already show the code within a P tag like this.

```
$("button").on("click", function() {
  $("#show-code-here p").text($("#code-within-container").html());
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of putting the results in a `p` tag just put them in a `pre` and it will keep the nesting as you have it

```
$("button").click(function(){
  $("#show-code-here pre").text($("#code-within-container").html());
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ef43uceL/)